# Delete content(DIV) by clicking on delete button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete the div and content inside when I click on the delete icon on the bottom left. How would I be able to do this? When the X is clicked, the content and div of the question goes away.

Here is the code.

```
<li class="question" id="question2">
    <div class="question-header curves dense-shadows">
        What color is the sky? 
    </div>
    <div class="question-content dense-shadows">
        <ol type="A">
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a1" name="question2" /> Red</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a2" name="question2" /> Green</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a3" name="question2" /> Blue</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="question2" /> Brown</li>
        </ol>
        <div style="text-align:right">

            <a href="#" class="delete"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/deletebutton.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/deletebuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/deletebutton.png'" title="Delete" alt="delete"/></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: @gezzuzz I do but it is just showing up as formatted.

Comment: find the parent, then use [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Comment: Do you want to actually delete it, or merely hide?

Comment: how would I actually do it? I want the question and options to be deleted whenever the delete icon is clicked.

Comment: @DVK if I hide, will there be empty space leftover or will there be the next visible div move up? I think I am trying to delete.

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="delete" onclick="document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('question2'))">
```

Comment: I want that function to happen when I click on the delete icon.

Comment: thanks a lot that works but is there a way to make it generalized like do this for any question, not just question2. And how can you do it if you want to hide instead of delete

Comment: the problem there is no link between the delete button and the question.. i assume you generate the question with some kind of script. that script can fill in that variable.. put question1 question2 question what ever..

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> yourDivToBeDeleted.innerHTML="";